# Getting verify certificate errors after adding Google Account & iCloud keychain problem?

Tags: icloud, email, security, gmail, keychain

I keep getting a verify certificate error whenever I add my Google Account.  The domina is an old company I used to work at and I have removed all account in reference to that account.  However I get the prompt to accept the certificate, I think, after adding my Google account.  Again there is no reference to this account anywhere.  I decided to check the logs and this is what I see. I've masked the actualy values with MY_OLD_COMPANY ETC. Any ideas how I could stop this from happening and remove any reference to this account? Again I don't have it setup ANYWHERE.

```
Jul 25 19:15:18 myComputer icbaccountsd[2520]: -[ICBAccountOperation createAccount]: Got bad password for an inactive account
Jul 25 19:15:18 myComputer icbaccountsd[2520]: -[ICBAccountOperation createAccount]: ***IAAccountCreator FAILED for: {
        IAAccountTypeKey = kIAServiceIMAP;
        IAMailOutgoingAuthenticationType = IAAuthSchemeClearText;
        IAMailOutgoingPortKey = 465;
        IAMailOutgoingUserNameKey = MY_OLD_COMPANY_USERNAME;
        accountDescription = MY_OLD_COMPANY_DESCRIPTION;
        authenticationType = IAAuthSchemeClearText;
        emailAddress = MY_OLD_COMPANY_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        fullName = MY_NAME;
        inactive = 1;
        incomingUseSSL = 1;
        outgoingMailServer = MY_OLD_COMPANY_MAIL_SERVER;
        outgoingUseSSL = 1;
        port = 993;
        userName = MY_OLD_USERNAME;
    }
```

Comment: Check your keychain and delete account and certificate.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That is the peculiar thing about this. I have deleted everything from my keychain and iCloud Keychain and I never see an entry for this.  But yet I don't know where and why this keeps happening.